# Problem in creating Widget using shadow dom and chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, shadow-dom

I have got a requirement where I have to create a chart widget using Shadow DOM and charts.js library.
I am able to create chart using html and CSS and javascript but when I am trying to do it using shadowDOM its not working for me.

I have provided the code that I wrote using css,html,javacript and using charts.js library in first part.

In second part I have provided the code that I created using shadowDOM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>My Chart</title>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    </div>

    <script>
        let myChart=document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        let typeofchart='horizontalBar'
        //Global Options

        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily='Lato';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize=18;
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor='Lato';

        let massPopChart=new Chart(myChart,{
            type:typeofchart,//bar,horizontalBar,pie,line,doughnut,radar,polarArea
            data:{
                labels:['Boston','Worcester','Springfield','Lowell','Cambridge','New Bedford'],
                datasets:[{
                    label:'Population',
                    data:[
                    617594,
                    181045,
                    153060,
                    106519,
                    105162,
                    95072
                    ],
                    //backgroundColor:'green'
                    backgroundColor:[
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)',
                    'rgba(54,162,235,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,206,86,0.6)',
                    'rgba(75,192,192,0.6)',
                    'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,159,64,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth:1,
                    borderColor:'#777',
                    hoverBorderWidth:3,
                    hoverBorderColor:'#000'

                }]
            },
            options:{
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
                    fontSize:25
                },
                legend:{
                    display:true,
                    position:'right',
                    labels:{
                        fontColor:'#000'
                    }
                },
                layout:{
                    padding:{
                        left:50,
                        right:0,
                        bottom:0,
                        top:0
                    }
                },
                tooltips:{
                    enabled:true
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The Corresponding code that I have written to create the same chart using ShadowDOM doesnt works.

```
(function()  {
    let tmpl = document.createElement('template');
    tmpl.innerHTML = `
    
        <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    `;

    customElements.define('com-sap-sample-helloworld1', class HelloWorld1 extends HTMLElement {


        constructor() {
            super(); 
            this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
            this._shadowRoot.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
            this._firstConnection = false;
        }

        //Fired when the widget is added to the html DOM of the page
        connectedCallback(){
            this._firstConnection = true;
            this.redraw();
        }

         //Fired when the widget is removed from the html DOM of the page (e.g. by hide)
        disconnectedCallback(){
        
        }

         //When the custom widget is updated, the Custom Widget SDK framework executes this function first
        onCustomWidgetBeforeUpdate(oChangedProperties) {

        }

        //When the custom widget is updated, the Custom Widget SDK framework executes this function after the update
        onCustomWidgetAfterUpdate(oChangedProperties) {
            if (this._firstConnection){
                this.redraw();
            }
        }
        
        //When the custom widget is removed from the canvas or the analytic application is closed
        onCustomWidgetDestroy(){
        }

        
        //When the custom widget is resized on the canvas, the Custom Widget SDK framework executes the following JavaScript function call on the custom widget
        // Commented out by default.  If it is enabled, SAP Analytics Cloud will track DOM size changes and call this callback as needed
        //  If you don't need to react to resizes, you can save CPU by leaving it uncommented.
        /*
        onCustomWidgetResize(width, height){
            redraw()
        }
        */

        redraw()
        {
        let chartsjssrc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js";
        let href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', chartsjssrc)
         let stylesheet = document.createElement('link')
         stylesheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
         stylesheet.setAttribute('href', href)
        let myChart=this._shadowRoot.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        let typeofchart='horizontalBar'
        //Global Options

        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily='Lato';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize=18;
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor='Lato';

        let massPopChart=new Chart(myChart,{
            type:typeofchart,//bar,horizontalBar,pie,line,doughnut,radar,polarArea
            data:{
                labels:['Boston','Worcester','Springfield','Lowell','Cambridge','New Bedford'],
                datasets:[{
                    label:'Population',
                    data:[
                    617594,
                    181045,
                    153060,
                    106519,
                    105162,
                    95072
                    ],
                    //backgroundColor:'green'
                    backgroundColor:[
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)',
                    'rgba(54,162,235,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,206,86,0.6)',
                    'rgba(75,192,192,0.6)',
                    'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,159,64,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth:1,
                    borderColor:'#777',
                    hoverBorderWidth:3,
                    hoverBorderColor:'#000'

                }]
            },
            options:{
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
                    fontSize:25
                },
                legend:{
                    display:true,
                    position:'right',
                    labels:{
                        fontColor:'#000'
                    }
                },
                layout:{
                    padding:{
                        left:50,
                        right:0,
                        bottom:0,
                        top:0
                    }
                },
                tooltips:{
                    enabled:true
                }
            }
        });
        }


    });
})();






Please tell what is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the myChart variable is actually targetted.

```js
let myChart=this._shadowRoot.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

console.log(myChart)
```

Also give the parent div a style of `display: block`

```css
     <div class="container" style='display: block'>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Remember styles are encapsulated in web components should in case you want to use a class to attach the styles.